# What is HTML5 Boilerplate?

Tags: html5boilerplate

I do not understand how people use HTML5Boilerplate with dynamic sites, like news sites, blogs, etc. I understand that you can get themes for WordPress, but specifically, I'm curious to know how sites like UpWorthy.com and DailyDot.com update when they are not using Wordpress or other identifiable CMS systems.

Can anyone explain?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Before there was Wordpress or a CMS, every website was custom made. All that was needed was a database and a backend language - which back in the day were JSP, ASP, and PHP. There were no pretty permalinks, so every URL ended in a query string with many parameters.

Those sites updated whenever their inhouse/outsourced IT team was ready to roll out an update. They were not a customized 'theme' but a 100% custom built.

They used boilerplate as a starting point of their templates and made modifications by making changes to those templates with whatever IDE company policy permits.

So the boiler plate is a starting point to create a completely custom website that ensures that as little as possible is missed by the developer.